# Why set operation did not print out in latex output?

Tags: math-mode, sharelatex

I used latex notation from [this](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols), and applied set operation on my latex context. Unfortunately, `sharelatex` did not print me out desired text, where set operation is missing still. How can I fix this problem? Why set operation did not show up in the text? Any quick solution please?

Here is my latex code:

```
r\textsubscript{ji} \in R\textsuperscript{w}\textsubscript{j} iff T\textsuperscript{s} \leqslant p\textsubscript{ji} < T\textsuperscript{w}
```

Here is the output of `sharelatex`:

[image]

Any quick hand to fix this issue? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have to use *math mode*: `$r_{ji}\in R^{w}_{j}$ iff $T_{s}\leqslang p_{ji} < T^{w}$`

Comment: @egreg Yes, it works, but I got additional error, it said: `\textsubscript invalid in math mode`. sorry for this simple question. Could you show your updated latex code here? Thx :)

Comment: Did I use `\textsubscript`? Rather than looking just a table, you should consult a beginner's guide, for instance http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html

Comment: @egreg I tried your solution like this: `$r\textsubscript{ji} \in R\textsuperscript{w}\textsubscript{j}$ iff $T\textsuperscript{s} \leqslant p\textsubscript{ji} < T\textsuperscript{w}$`, but I got additional error instead. Hope you could help me out :)

Comment: Did you try the code I wrote (sorry for the typo in `\leqslant`)? You mustn't use `\textsuperscript{w}`, but `^{w}`.

Comment: Of course you don't. Spending some time on an introductory guide will allow you to proceed more quickly.

Comment: If you insist on using \textsuperscript, at least use $\leqslang$.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am fresh to work with `latex`, and using `textsuperscript` is just one case. Hope you could point me out other possibility for same question (using under score, upper score for mathematics notation)

Comment: LaTeX uses different rules for typesetting math and text, and certain commands can only be used in one or the other modes. $r_{ij}$ and r\textsubscript{ij} produce similar results, but using different fonts and spacing.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I would like to further explore the features of `latex`. Could you point me out some resources which fits for beginner like me? Thanks :)

Comment: My first guide was the TeXbook by Knuth (back when it was the only reference).  There are a number of online tutorials available, and LaTeX guides for beginners.